# Not getting token from ionic push.register

Tags: javascript, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am not getting a token when registering my ionic app for ionic push.

In my app.js within the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` function I have:

```js
Ionic.io();
var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true
});
push.register(function(token) {
    alert("Device token:",token.token);
});
```

In my index.html file I have:

```html
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

<!-- Next four added for ionic push service -->
<script src="lib/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script> -->
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-push/ionic-push.js"></script>
```

I have done all of the things shown at: [ionic push quick start](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-quick-start)

The alert shows but there is no token.

I am using an iPhone connected to my MacBook running XCode.

Comment: can you add some log, so I can help you bro //??

Comment: What kind of log do you want to see? The XCode log?

Answer (score 0):

> Test with a phone
>   In the browser does not work for the token

Android plug it in Debug mode

```
ionic run android -c -l
```

You can use

```
//app.js
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });
  });
})
```

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch

Comment: I am currently just using an iPhone plugged into the MacBook/XCode